Cannot deploy and debug MAUI app with iOS 18 beta and Macos 15 beta
I had to update my iphone to iOS beta and mac to 15 beta as well. But now I have to write some code in maui. It's all ok until I want to run my code on simulator or device. It end up with error when try to debug:

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/bin/mlaunch --launchsim /{app_path}/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MyApp.app --device=:v2:udid=BAECFA41-6785-4593-BDDA-F4A4AC1D9FC1 -sdk 18.0 --argument=-monodevelop-port --argument=10001 --setenv=XAMARIN_DEBUG_PORT=10001 --sdkroot /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
error HE0004: Could not load the framework 'IDEDistribution' (path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEDistribution.framework/Versions/A/IDEDistribution):
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEDistribution.framework/Versions/A/IDEDistribution, 0x0001): Library not loaded: @rpath/AppThinning.framework/Versions/A/AppThinning
Referenced from: <75213748-5F57-3584-9A4B-299BBE6F3D0B> /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEDistribution.framework/Versions/A/IDEDistribution
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/Frameworks/AppThinning.framework/Versions/A/AppThinning' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEDistribution.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppThinning.framework/Versions/A/AppThinning' (no such file), '/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/Frameworks/AppThinning.framework/Versions/A/AppThinning' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/IDEDistribution.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppThinning.framework/Versions/A/AppThinning' (no such file), '/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/lib/mlaunch/mlaunch.app/Contents/MonoBundle/AppThinning.framework/Versions/A/AppThinning' (no such file)

I also tried with old stable XCode and then try to make it work but that didn't work either. Any suggestions? The only way is to downgrade and/or wait to release stable systems and wait for update tooling?

The current Xcode beta is not supported yet, so yeah, you'll have to downgrade!

@GeraldVersluis downgrade of iOS should be enough?

I'm afraid not. In fact iOS will work, I've been deploying to iOS 18 but Xcode won't work and downgrading probably means downgrading macOS too. Had to reformat my whole machine 2 weeks ago because I accidentally upgraded

.Net8 MAUI currently does not support iOS beta and macOS beta version, for this you can refer to Supported platforms for .NET MAUI apps.
Based on past experience, .Net will provide support after the official release of iOS and macOS, or you can post this issue to GitHub to find the exact time node.
